# How to set values for particular cells in pandas.Dataframe correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've created a pandas DataFrame

`df = DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(3,5), columns=['a','b','c', 'd', 'e'])`

```
df  a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
```

And I want to set values for particular cells:

```
flag = df['b'] > 3 

df[flag]['b']=10
```

But it **doesn't** work.

```
df  a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
```

I use the following codes. **It works, but i don't know why?**

`df['b'][flag] = 10`

```
df  a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5  10   7   8   9
2  10  10  12  13  14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use chained indexing for assigning values.

Instead, use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to specify rows and columns:

```
df.loc[df['b'] > 3, 'b'] = 10
```

The `.loc` indexer accepts lists, scalars, or Boolean arrays.

The `pandas` docs [explain in detail](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) why chained indexing should be avoided.